# kmeans cluster Newbie

Tags: python, numpy, k-means, inertiajs

I'm new to Python and running through a cluster intro demo.  However, the code gets stuck at one point and I was hoping someone could help me resolve this.

```
    # Import the library
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans# To make sure our work becomes reproducible
np.random.seed(42)inertia = []# Iterating the process
for i in range(2, 10):
  # Instantiate the model
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=i)
  # Fit The Model
    model.fit(X_transformed)
  # Extract the error of the model
    inertia.append(model.inertia_)# Visualize the model
sns.pointplot(x=list(range(2, 10)), y=inertia)
plt.title('SSE on K-Means based on # of clusters')
plt.show()
```

**This is the error message I get:**

```
      File "<ipython-input-32-95dac55492e9>", line 3
    np.random.seed(42)inertia = []# Iterating the process
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

many thanks

Comment: `Inertia = []` should be in new line

Answer (score 0):

inertial should be new line

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans# To make sure our work becomes reproducible
np.random.seed(42)
inertia = []# Iterating the process
```